# How to insert a variable value into table?

Tags: python-2.6, cx-oracle

Suppose i have the following file.csv

```
DATE    Name    Email
26-Sep-19   Name1   Name1@email.com 
26-Sep-19   Name2   Name2@email.com 
26-Sep-19   Name3   Name3@email.com
```

I am trying to insert values from file.csv into a table

```
import cx_Oracle
import csv
import os
from datetime import datetime

con = cx_Oracle.connect(uname, pwd, hostname + ': ' + port + '/' + service)
cursor = con.cursor()

with open('file.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for lines in csv_reader:
        cursor.execute( "INSERT INTO table1 ( DATE,Name,Email) values (:1, :2, :3)", 
        (lines[0],lines[1],lines[2])  
cursor.close()
con.commit()
con.close()
```

I get this error:

> (lines[0],lines[1],lines[2]) cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01858: a
>   non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

After some debugging, i was able to nail it down to the issue being with the date, so instead of lines[0], i replaced with hard-coded date, and it worked!

```
cursor.execute( "INSERT INTO table1 ( DATE,Name,Email) values (:1, :2, :3)", 
('26-Sep-19',lines[1],lines[2])
```

why is it not working with `lines[0]` variable but with a hardcoded value its working just fine?

Comment: Does the value of `lines[0]` follow the same format as `'26-Sep-19'`?

Comment: @blhsing yes it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you've solved the date format issue, consider using `executemany()` for performance.  Something like:

With file.csv containing:

```
26-Sep-19,Name1,Name1@email.com 
26-Sep-19,Name2,Name2@email.com 
26-Sep-19,Name3,Name3@email.com
```

and the table created like:

```
create table table1 ("DATE" date, name varchar2(20), email varchar2(20));
```

Then this file using the date conversion that @anthony mentioned works:

```
# Set cursor sizes to match the table definition or known max data sizes
#   create table table1 ("DATE" date, name varchar2(20), email varchar2(20));
cursor.setinputsizes(None, 20, 20)

# Adjust the batch size to meet your memory and performance requirements
batchSize = 1000

with open('file.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    i = 0
    data = []
    for line in csv_reader:
        data.append((line[0],line[1],line[2]))
        i = i + 1
        if (i % batchSize == 0):
            print('batch')
            cursor.executemany("""insert into table1 ("DATE",name, email) values (to_date(:1, 'DD-Mon-YY'), :2, :3)""", data)
            data = []
            i = 0
    if (i % batchSize != 0):
        print('final')
        cursor.executemany("""insert into table1 ("DATE",name, email) values (to_date(:1, 'DD-Mon-YY'), :2, :3)""", data)
    con.commit()
```

To load some rows to a DB on the far side of the world took 4 seconds with a similar script (mostly connection time costs) vs 36 seconds with `execute()`

Comment: Interesting! I was indeed seeing slow execution with execute() especially with the 4k or so rows in the csv file.

Comment: Documentation on `executemany()` is at  https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html

Comment: Hey I tried your answer because Anthony's answer didnt work for me, and I still get the same non numeric numeric error :/

Comment: I tried the hardcoded value and it worked, but without hardcoded value it complains yet again about the numeric vs nonnumeric like in the quest I have

Comment: Finally, it worked! The issue was indeeed the header line! And the double quotes required around date!

Answer (score 2):

The string format of your date must match what Oracle is expecting. You can set the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` parameter for your session, or you can simply modify your code to do something like the following instead:

```
cursor.execute("""
        insert into table1 (date, name, email)
        values (to_date(:1, 'dd-Mon-YY'), :2, :3)""",
        (lines[0], lines[1], lines[2]))
```

Comment: Did not work, still getting the same non numeric error :/

Comment: Did you strip (or skip) the header line from the CSV file? And you are likely to have other issues if you try to use a column name called DATE.  You might need to use double quotes around it, depending how the table was created.

Comment: And don't forget the data file should have commas in it, but you show spaces.

Comment: I updated the code in my answer to incorporate your data and @anthony's date cast

Comment: @Christopher Jones i missed your replies here even though I kept checking because I wasnt tagged it seems. I think you meant to comment on your answer since it doesn't require tagging. Thank you so much though!